# Showing z value as an annotation when z value is >0.85 Tripcolor Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, triangulation

I have problem similar to tripcolor demo example. 
I have lon,lat , z values which i am plotting using Tripcolor i want to show annotation as lon value,lat value and z value at particular lon,lat location if my z value is less than 0.70.

For Example in below code , i want an annotation / popup message show in my plot which show lon value, lat value and z value at location lon=-2 lat=55 show annotation if z value is less than 0.70 i.e if zvalue is greater than 0.70 then in plot show me lon value lat value and zvalue.I want plot similar to the image provided. Thank you.

```
xy = np.asarray([
[-0.101, 0.872], [-0.080, 0.883], [-0.069, 0.888], [-0.054, 0.890],
[-0.045, 0.897], [-0.057, 0.895], [-0.073, 0.900], [-0.087, 0.898],
[-0.090, 0.904], [-0.069, 0.907], [-0.069, 0.921], [-0.080, 0.919],
[-0.073, 0.928], [-0.052, 0.930], [-0.048, 0.942], [-0.062, 0.949],
[-0.054, 0.958], [-0.069, 0.954], [-0.087, 0.952], [-0.087, 0.959],
[-0.080, 0.966], [-0.085, 0.973], [-0.087, 0.965], [-0.097, 0.965],
[-0.097, 0.975], [-0.092, 0.984], [-0.101, 0.980], [-0.108, 0.980],
[-0.104, 0.987], [-0.102, 0.993], [-0.115, 1.001], [-0.099, 0.996],
[-0.101, 1.007], [-0.090, 1.010], [-0.087, 1.021], [-0.069, 1.021],
[-0.052, 1.022], [-0.052, 1.017], [-0.069, 1.010], [-0.064, 1.005],
[-0.048, 1.005], [-0.031, 1.005], [-0.031, 0.996], [-0.040, 0.987],
[-0.045, 0.980], [-0.052, 0.975], [-0.040, 0.973], [-0.026, 0.968],
[-0.020, 0.954], [-0.006, 0.947], [ 0.003, 0.935], [ 0.006, 0.926],
[ 0.005, 0.921], [ 0.022, 0.923], [ 0.033, 0.912], [ 0.029, 0.905],
[ 0.017, 0.900], [ 0.012, 0.895], [ 0.027, 0.893], [ 0.019, 0.886],
[ 0.001, 0.883], [-0.012, 0.884], [-0.029, 0.883], [-0.038, 0.879],
[-0.057, 0.881], [-0.062, 0.876], [-0.078, 0.876], [-0.087, 0.872],
[-0.030, 0.907], [-0.007, 0.905], [-0.057, 0.916], [-0.025, 0.933],
[-0.077, 0.990], [-0.059, 0.993]])
x, y = np.rad2deg(xy).T

triangles = np.asarray([
[67, 66,  1], [65,  2, 66], [ 1, 66,  2], [64,  2, 65], [63,  3, 64],
[60, 59, 57], [ 2, 64,  3], [ 3, 63,  4], [ 0, 67,  1], [62,  4, 63],
[57, 59, 56], [59, 58, 56], [61, 60, 69], [57, 69, 60], [ 4, 62, 68],
[ 6,  5,  9], [61, 68, 62], [69, 68, 61], [ 9,  5, 70], [ 6,  8,  7],
[ 4, 70,  5], [ 8,  6,  9], [56, 69, 57], [69, 56, 52], [70, 10,  9],
[54, 53, 55], [56, 55, 53], [68, 70,  4], [52, 56, 53], [11, 10, 12],
[69, 71, 68], [68, 13, 70], [10, 70, 13], [51, 50, 52], [13, 68, 71],
[52, 71, 69], [12, 10, 13], [71, 52, 50], [71, 14, 13], [50, 49, 71],
[49, 48, 71], [14, 16, 15], [14, 71, 48], [17, 19, 18], [17, 20, 19],
[48, 16, 14], [48, 47, 16], [47, 46, 16], [16, 46, 45], [23, 22, 24],
[21, 24, 22], [17, 16, 45], [20, 17, 45], [21, 25, 24], [27, 26, 28],
[20, 72, 21], [25, 21, 72], [45, 72, 20], [25, 28, 26], [44, 73, 45],
[72, 45, 73], [28, 25, 29], [29, 25, 31], [43, 73, 44], [73, 43, 40],
[72, 73, 39], [72, 31, 25], [42, 40, 43], [31, 30, 29], [39, 73, 40],
[42, 41, 40], [72, 33, 31], [32, 31, 33], [39, 38, 72], [33, 72, 38],
[33, 38, 34], [37, 35, 38], [34, 38, 35], [35, 37, 36]])

 xmid = x[triangles].mean(axis=1)
 ymid = y[triangles].mean(axis=1)
 x0 = -5
 y0 = 52
zfaces = np.exp(-0.01 * ((xmid - x0) * (xmid - x0) +
                     (ymid - y0) * (ymid - y0)))
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.set_aspect('equal')
tpc = ax3.tripcolor(x, y, triangles, facecolors=zfaces, edgecolors='k')
fig3.colorbar(tpc)
ax3.set_title('tripcolor of user-specified triangulation')
ax3.set_xlabel('Longitude (degrees)')
ax3.set_ylabel('Latitude (degrees)')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St6PK.png)
    #final image link 
[image]

Comment: 1) Which one is it: 0.7 or 0.8?

Comment: 2) Half your zfaces are above 0.8, nearly all of them above 0.7. Do you want to show the annotations all the time or only when you hover over the triangle?

Comment: I need to make gif final output so hover won't work as i think in gif file (combining all the image plots) . My Apology if the zvalues is less than 0.7 then it will be easy to give annotation message.

Answer (score 0):

Voila, but in my opinion, you are trying to annotate way too much.

Adding the following snippet, yields the image below:

```
indices, = np.where(zfaces > 0.8)
for idx in indices:
    xx, yy, zz = xmid[idx], ymid[idx], zfaces[idx]
    ax3.annotate(f'x={xx:.2f}\ny={yy:.2f}\nz={zz:.2f}', (xx, yy),
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 fontsize='xx-small',
                 color='black')
```

[image]

Here is a slightly better option:

```
indices, = np.where(zfaces > 0.8)
for idx in indices:
    xx, yy, zz = xmid[idx], ymid[idx], zfaces[idx]
    ax3.annotate(f'{zz:.2f}', (xx, yy),
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 fontsize='xx-small',
                 color='white')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot Paul for such a quick reply .

Comment: @MSAmsa Glad I could help. If the answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Really great and i appreciate ur help but i have more than 1 lakh of points so this solution / logic is not feasible in my case , Now i am thinking instead of showing value in plot i will be writing lon value lat value z value into a new file tab separated where z value is less than 0.70 .

Comment: Hi Paul Brodersen
@Paul Brodersen , 
I want that z value below 0.75 should be in white color and in colorbar as well below 0.75 in  white color ,
**I have tried       cmap.set_under('white', 0.0)
            pp.cmap.set_under('white', 0.0)
But not working .**